# Convert Javascript Associative Object and Output it in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, object, foreach

Using Javascript i create an associative object called 'basketItems'. (that resembles an associative array) I then add 'item' objects to this which hold certain item specifications as can be seen below:

```
// create main basketItems Object
var basketItems = new Object();

function createItem() {
    var item = new Object();
    item["number"] = number variable;     
    item["color"] = color variable;
    item["engine"] = engine variable;
    item["shape"] = shape variable;
    item["seats"] = seats variable;
    item["price"] = price variable;

    var itemUnique = unique variable;

    // Add Item into BasketItems Object
    basketItems[itemUnique] = item;
}
```

I then send basketItems to the server using post and on the server side my PHP code is:

```
<?php
$basketItems = $_POST['items'];
print $basketItems;
?>
```

This gives me the complete basketItems object and outputs it like below as an example:

```
{ 546523 = { seats = \"FOUR\"; shape = \"HATCHBACK\"; price = \"6500\"; engine = \"TWO LITRE\"; color = \"ORANGE\"; number = \"36408974\"; }; }
```

I need to be able to call specific parts of the basketItems object though and not just the complete contents. I have tried several attempts using the 'foreach' statement below but i always get an **invalid foreach argument**:

```
<?php
$basketItems = $_POST['items'];

foreach($basketItems as $key => $item) {
print $item['shape'];
}
?>
```

How could i achieve the above so that i can pick out say just the 'shape' value for all items in the basketItems Object?

If anyone could help me out on this i would really appreciate it.

Thank you in advance

---------------------**Quick Update**--------------------

The javascript is all being used in a mobile app being built in Titanium Appcelerator.
I am not posting it with JSON, just as a standard object. The post is sent as below:

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://www.xxxxxx.com/xxxxxx.php');
xhr.onload = function () {webview.html = this.responseText;};
xhr.send({items:basketItems});
```

Comment: The syntax doesn't match at various places. Can you give a real example of any of the data?

Comment: How are you posting it to the PHP? As JSON?

Comment: Hi Mario, it should be 90% correct to what i am using. I have just been asked to change some of the variable names etc by the client. Where abouts are the syntax issues as it may have just been a typo by me...

Comment: 90% isn't close enough. The structure *must be exact*, even if you change the identifiers.

Comment: After some consideration I believe your actual problem lies in `Using Javascript i create an associative object` and this is foremost a Javascript question. Show your relevant request code there.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your example data is all wrong. But if your input was JSON then it'd be something like:

[`[ { "seats": "FOUR", "shape": "HATCHBACK", "price": "6500", "engine": "TWO LITRE", "color": "ORANGE", "number": "36408974" } ]`](http://array.include-once.org/?foreach=1&assoc=1&json=%5B+%7B+%22seats%22%3A+%22FOUR%22%2C+%22shape%22%3A+%22HATCHBACK%22%2C+%22price%22%3A+%226500%22%2C+%22engine%22%3A+%22TWO+LITRE%22%2C+%22color%22%3A+%22ORANGE%22%2C+%22number%22%3A+%2236408974%22+%7D+%5D)

Note that the same traversal would apply for an actual $_POST array. And it should be exactly like your example foreach.

The input you've shown is neither. It looks like some magic_quotes hampered JSON, but I'm not really sure.

Otherwise before you try anything else, use `var_dump($_POST);` to see the actual received structure, before you loop over it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this suppose to be a JSON string? If yes, it's incorrect format.

```
{ 546523 = { seats = \"FOUR\"; shape = \"HATCHBACK\"; price = \"6500\"; engine = \"TWO LITRE\"; color = \"ORANGE\"; number = \"36408974\"; }; }
```

The value of $basketItems  is a string not an array. Use json_decode http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php to decode JSON string and then you can loop over an array.

```
$basketItems = $_POST['items']; 

foreach($basketItems as $key => $item) {
print $item['shape'];
}
```